# Can't fetch an api key using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to get different `sumbols` and their `values` from a webpage. I used this [sitelink](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/#ratings) to collect the desired content but I could notice that he content of that page generates dynamically so I used their [api](https://platform-api.flipsidecrypto.com/api/v1/metrics/FCAS/assets?api_key=6e9c2808-0c48-41d8-81f1-5363d5ceb1af&visual_distribution=true) which I've collected using chrome dev tools.

There is an `api_key` associated with that `api`.

How can I fetch that api key using script which I've collected using chrome dev tools?

I've written so far (working flawlessly):

```
import requests

url = "https://platform-api.flipsidecrypto.com/api/v1/metrics/FCAS/assets?"

params = {'api_key': '6e9c2808-0c48-41d8-81f1-5363d5ceb1af'}

res = requests.get(url,params=params)
for item in res.json():
    print(item['asset_name'],item['value'])
```

Comment: I don't think i understand your question, you want to get the API key in an automated fashion?

Comment: I don't understand it too. You show code which use API KEY but you ask how to get API KEY. Can't you create Python script which will load web page and search KEY in HTML file or JS file ?

Comment: at the bottom of this page you have link [Crypto API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) - it seems you can register and get own API KEY for free. For free you can make 10 000 request/month - see [prices](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/pricing/)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly I meant @David Silveiro.

Comment: can't you register and get API KEY for free ?

Comment: I can get that in several different ways but what my question here is how I can fetch that automatically @furas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Selenium has access to DevTools, but I see few methods which maybe could work. As I know old version could access browser menu but newer version can't so it may not have access to DevTools too.

1. key can be in some file HTML or JS. Script can get HTML and search key in HTML. It can also get links to JS, load them and search key. But problem is how to recognize key - it can be after `api_key=` or not. It can be also hidden ie. with base64. You would have to first find it manually and see how to recognize place with key.
2. run local proxy server and configure browser to use this server. I use some proxy server with GUI to check links manualy but there is python proxy server [mitmpy](https://mitmproxy.org/) (Man-In-The-Middle-Py) and you can use python to access this server when it is running
3. I don't know if Selenium has access to DevTools in Chrome/Firefox - I never had to check it. But maybe there is Firefox extension which could save all requests to file (or maybe I would try to create extension with JavaScript) and this way I could get links with key. It would be half-automated method.

Comment: I don't know much about selenium but I can access the dev tools using `puppeteer` in `node` using `puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, devtools: true })`. thanks for the pointer @furas.